# Zend Server resets to defaults on Zend Studio 10 startup

Tags: apache2, port, zend-studio, zend-server, document-root

I' m running Zend Server 6.0.1 and Zend Studio 10 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. Because Zend Servers Apache listens to port 10088 by default on Mac OS, I changed that in Apache configuration file to port 80. Additionally I changed document root to /Users/username/Sites. Both changes work as they should.

Unfortunately every time I start Zend Studio 10 it detects my Zend Server as new Server and configures it automatically. It resets my PHP Server settings to port 10088 and erases the Zend Server password. When I change that detected Server to my real settings (port 80) that changes last until I restart my Zend Studio.

Can anybody tell me how to make Zend Server know that it's apache listens to port 80 instead of 10088? That would also fixed my problem with Application Deployment which always wants to deploy to localhost:10088.